# How can I "auto send" the instance of the calling object within the bind function?

Tags: c++, bind

[Here's my code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fec581812ff2461b):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Voice
{
public:
    double mVoiceValue = 0.0;
    std::function<double(Voice &, double)> mTargetFunction;

    Voice(std::function<double(Voice &, double)> targetFunction) : mTargetFunction(targetFunction) { }
    ~Voice() { }    

private:
};

class Osc
{
public:
    double mOscValue = 1.0;

    Osc() { }
    ~Osc() { }

    double Modulate(Voice &voice, double value) {
        return mOscValue * voice.mVoiceValue * value;
    }

private:
};

int main()
{
    Osc *osc = new Osc();
    Voice voice1(std::bind(&Osc::Modulate, osc, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
    Voice voice2(std::bind(&Osc::Modulate, osc, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

    voice1.mVoiceValue = 1.0;
    voice2.mVoiceValue = 2.0;
    std::cout << "value: " << voice1.mTargetFunction(voice1, 10.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value: " << voice2.mTargetFunction(voice2, 100.0) << std::endl;
}
```

I'd like to non passing the `voice1`/`voice2` instances (i.e. itself) to the calling bind function. Since I'd like to directly send that instance because its the same of the calling object.

How can I bind in this way?

i.e. It must return the same results calling:

```
std::cout << "value: " << voice1.mTargetFunction(10.0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "value: " << voice2.mTargetFunction(100.0) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Provide a method on `Voice` that calls `mTargetFunction(*this, whatever);`. Then call it like `voice1.callTarget(10.0);`

Comment: Be aware that you make 2 copies of `osc` object when you bind.

Comment: @Slava: what do you mean with "you make 2 copies of osc"?

Comment: @paizza when you will call `Osc::Modulate` through that binded object that would be invoked on a copy of osc. For example if that method would make change to object itself that would not be visible in `osc` or in one that passed to the second bind. You pass `osc` by value. See the answer and why `std::ref` is used there

Comment: Oh yeah, of course! My typo. On my real code I have `Osc *osc = new Osc();` which works like a sharm without `std::ref` ;) Thanks to spot it out, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay for the `Voice` constructor to take *two* arguments (the `Osc` object and the member function pointer) you can solve it something like this:

```
class Voice
{
public:
    double mVoiceValue = 0.0;
    std::function<double(double)> mTargetFunction;

    template<typename T, typename F>
    Voice(T& targetObject, F&& targetFunction)
        : mTargetFunction(std::bind(targetFunction, targetObject, std::ref(*this), std::placeholders::_1)) { }
    ~Voice() { }
};

class Osc
{
public:
    double mOscValue = 1.0;

    Osc() { }
    ~Osc() { }

    double Modulate(Voice &voice, double value) {
        return mOscValue * voice.mVoiceValue * value;
    }
};

...

Osc   osc;
Voice voice1(osc, &Osc::Modulate);
Voice voice2(osc, &Osc::Modulate);

voice1.mVoiceValue = 1.0;
voice2.mVoiceValue = 2.0;
std::cout << "value: " << voice1.mTargetFunction(10.0) << std::endl;
std::cout << "value: " << voice2.mTargetFunction(100.0) << std::endl;
```

The important bit here is the usage of `std::ref` for the `Voice` argument.

If it always is the `Modulate` member function that is going to be called, then the `Voice` constructor doesn't have to take the pointer to the member function as argument, and then use `&T::Modulate` in the call to `std::bind`.

Comment: I don't want to use template.

Comment: @paizza Then unless you will *always* use an `Osc` you really have no choice: Either your solution or my solution with templates. Of you will *only* use `Osc` objects, then make a forward declaration and hard-code its use. Optionally create multiple overloads of the `Voice` constructor, each taking a pointer to member function for each object you might use.

Comment: What do you mean with "you will always use an Osc"? I want to use the `Osc::Modulate` function of `osc`, for every voice. Slave said "Be aware that you make 2 copies of osc object when you bind." Not sure what he means. Maybe its related?

Comment: isn't `F&& targetFunction` a universal reference? if yes then shouldn't it be std::forward-ed to std::bind ?

Comment: @paizza I mean, will you *ever* use some other class or member function? Will it *always* be `Osc` and `Osc::Modulate`? Then you have to use a solution like mine, or what you already have. On the other hand, if you will *always* use `Osc::Modulate` there's simply no need for binding and all that.

Comment: First, I did a typo. Was `Osc *osc = new Osc();` (and not `Osc osc`;). So I pass it a pointer). Second: this is a classic way to do it. Your solution use template, which I don't want for some reasons. Mine, its not what I want. i.e. I pass every time "voice", which don't need I think since its the caller. That's all...! I can't pass "myself" to a function as implicit parameter?